# Error: nexrender: Can't find a property sequence Color for key: Colorwithin layer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, after-effects

[After effect THE WEDDING Layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Stow.png), [After effect Shape Layer 4 Layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCHeI.png)

I want to change the font color of THE WEDDING and I want to change the background color of Shape Layer 4 so I have tried with the below type of JSON but none of these are working.

1.

```
"assets": [
  {
    "type": "data",
    "layerName": "THE WEDDING",
    "property": "Color",
   "value": [1.0, 0.5, 0, 0]
  }
  {
    "type": "data",
    "layerName": "Shape Layer 4",
    "property": "Color",
   "value": [1.0, 0.5, 0, 0]
  }
]
```

Error: Error: nexrender: Can't find a property sequence Color for key: Colorwithin layer: Shape Layer 4

2.

```
"assets": [
  {
    "type": "data",
    "layerName": "THE WEDDING",
    "property": "Effects.Skin_Color.Color",
    "value": [1, 0, 0]
  }
  {
    "type": "data",
    "layerName": "Shape Layer 4",
    "property": "Effects.Skin_Color.Color",
    "value": [1, 0, 0]
  }
]
```

Error: Error: Error: nexrender: Can't find a property sequence Color for key: Effects.Skin_Color.Color layer: Shape Layer 4

Can anyone help here ?